# df.loc[rows, [col]] vs df.loc[rows, col] in assignment

Tags: pandas

What do the following assignments behave differently?

```
df.loc[rows, [col]] = ...
df.loc[rows, col] = ...
```

For example:

```
r = pd.DataFrame({"response": [1,1,1],},index = [1,2,3] )
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [999,99,9],}, index = [3,4,5] )
df = pd.merge(df, r, how="left", left_index=True, right_index=True)

df.loc[df["response"].isnull(), "response"] = 0
print df
     x  response
3  999       0.0
4   99       0.0
5    9       0.0
```

but

```
df.loc[df["response"].isnull(), ["response"]] = 0
print df
     x  response
3  999       1.0
4   99       0.0
5    9       0.0
```

why should I expect the first to behave differently to the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.loc[df["response"].isnull(), ["response"]]
```

returns a DataFrame, so if you want to assign something to it it must be aligned by both index **and columns**

Demo:

```
In [79]: df.loc[df["response"].isnull(), ["response"]] = \
             pd.DataFrame([11,12], columns=['response'], index=[4,5])

In [80]: df
Out[80]:
     x  response
3  999       1.0
4   99      11.0
5    9      12.0
```

alternatively you can assign an array/matrix of the same shape:

```
In [83]: df.loc[df["response"].isnull(), ["response"]] = [11, 12]

In [84]: df
Out[84]:
     x  response
3  999       1.0
4   99      11.0
5    9      12.0
```

I'd also consider using `fillna()` method:

```
In [88]: df.response = df.response.fillna(0)

In [89]: df
Out[89]:
     x  response
3  999       1.0
4   99       0.0
5    9       0.0
```

Comment: Doesn't df.loc[df["response"].isnull(), "response"] also return a dataframe?

Comment: Ahh -- so it does.